# Aborted connection to db; docker-compose ruby & mysql images - Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to run a rails app with mysql db docker image.

The **docker-compose build** goes fine; the **docker-compose up** goes fine as well, even though there are some warnings (mysql image version issues)

```
...
db_1 | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db_1 | [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
...
db_1 | [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1 | [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1 | [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1 | Version: '5.7.10' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db_1 | Version: '5.7.10' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
web_1 | [2016-02-11 18:38:10] INFO WEBrick 1.3.1
web_1 | [2016-02-11 18:38:10] INFO ruby 2.2.0 (2014-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
web_1 | [2016-02-11 18:38:10] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=3000
```

When I run migration commands **docker-compose run web rake db:create|migrate** on another terminal, I get this errors, in the current one (**docker-compose up**):

```
db_1 | [Note] Aborted connection 2 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '172.17.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
...
db_1 | [Note] Aborted connection 3 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '172.17.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

This is my ***Dockerfile***:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
EXPOSE 3000
```

This is my ***docker-compose.yml***:

```
    db:
  image: mysql:latest
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

This is my ***database.yml***:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  encoding: utf8
  host: db
  username: root
  password: password    
development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

For more details, see the [entire scenario](https://gist.github.com/embasbm/0fa8c1aa469c921ddcd3)

Comment: I also have this issue but not exclusively from our docker containers...

Comment: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/606

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or get around it? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Is there any solution ? I have this problem so